# MySQL: Accounting for NULL or 0 values when multiple joins exist on one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that looks up people's full names based on their record ID's in a table called `users`. The full names are tied to their roles in another table (`table1`). This requires multiple joins to the `users` table:

```
SELECT table1.id, users.full_name AS "Requester", 
users.full_name AS "Approver," 
users.full_name AS "Ordered By", 
users.full_name AS "Received By" 
FROM table1
JOIN users AS users
ON table1.requester_id = users.id
JOIN users AS users2
ON table1.approver_id = users2.id
JOIN users AS users3 
ON table1.ordered_by = users3.id
JOIN users AS users4
ON table1.received_by = users4.id
WHERE table1.deleted_record !=1;
```

The problem I'm having is with `ordered_by` and `received_by`. Often, they don't yet exist, because the order has neither been ordered nor received, so the ID for each can be 0, which has no corresponding value in the `users`table. When I run this query, I should get back all 475 records that exist, but I only get back 365, because of those 0 values. How can I modify this query to make sure all rows are returned, even if `ordered_by` and/or `received_by` = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `left join`:

```
SELECT t1.id, ur.full_name AS "Requester", 
       ua.full_name AS "Approver," 
       uo.full_name AS "Ordered By", 
       urv.uo AS "Received By" 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     users ur
     ON t1.requester_id = ur.id LEFT JOIN
     users ua
     ON t1.approver_id = ua.id LEFT JOIN
     users uo 
     ON t1.ordered_by = uo.id LEFT JOIN
     users urv
     ON t1.received_by = urv.id
WHERE t1.deleted_record <> 1;
```

Note that I changed the aliases on the `users` references from fairly meaningless `u1`, `u2`, etc. to `ua`, `uo`, and so on.  Also, these need to be used in the `SELECT` to get the right full name.

Comment: Thanks. I started out with INNER JOINs and backed those out when I didn't get my desired result. LEFT JOIN fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

First, your primary table driving the query should be `table1`. Then, you are using `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` will give you a null result if no link, but not fail. In which case, you might have to use an `IF` for your fields value

```
SELECT table1.id, req.full_name AS "Requester", 
   app.full_name AS "Approver", 
   ordr.full_name AS "Ordered By", 
   rec.full_name AS "Received By" 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN users AS req
   ON table1.requester_id = req.id
LEFT JOIN users AS app
   ON table1.approver_id = app.id
LEFT JOIN users AS ordr
   ON table1.ordered_by = ordr.id
LEFT JOIN users AS rec
   ON table1.received_by = rec.id
WHERE table1.deleted_record !=1;
```

This should do it

Comment: table1 does drive the query. I typed the wrong table name. It's fixed now.